# PHP function preg_match is not functioning precisley

Tags: php

I use a preg_match_all() function to count the number of words.

What I have found out is that it removes the numbers from the content. Why? Here is the function:

```
define("WORD_COUNT_MASK", "/\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{Mn}\\p{Pd}'\\x{2019}]*/u");
$matches;
    function str_word_count_utf8($str)
    {        
        global $matches;
        return preg_match_all(WORD_COUNT_MASK, $str, $matches);      
    }
```

What do you think is causing this issue??

Comment: http://www.php.net/str_word_count :)

Comment: i want a solution for my current function. Also, str_word_count does not support non-latin

Comment: `str_word_count` supports non-latin chars. Take a look at its third parameter.